Movie on an middle-ages alien planet where everyone is tall and grey, with guards riding hippo-like creatures
I watched it around 2008 - 2010, but it might be way older. All I remember is one scene. It all happened on a different planet. Everyone was alien. They were tall, grey and it looked like they lived in middle ages. The main colour scheme was green, I think.
There were guards riding animals (that I would describe as hippo-like) and anteaters (face of anteater and hippo, but with long legs) and they rode to some kind of gathering. Then there was a woman and they killed her father. I think it happened when she wasn't there and some kind of punishment. I remember her shock and pain when she found her dad. The people were like starting to rebel against those guards.

Star Wars: The Phantom Menace? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1rO06hp6C8&ab_channel=JUMENTERTAIN

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Was this animation, or live action (with special effects)?

Given the mention of hippo-like mounts, could it be John Carter? It has tall, grey-type aliens who live in an approximately medieval setting, but it came out after your year range, the aliens are notably green, the colours are more orange-tinted, and there is one non-alien human in the cast.

Though arguably, John Carter, the one human is the alien and everyone else native, given that it is set on Mars and John is from Earth.
